# what are path and environment variables, and how I set or use them?

Tags: windows

I have tried to set the environment variables through command prompt and through control panel. but when i run the echo command its not showing the added path. Please help me to add the path.

Comment: "when i run the echo command its not showing the added path" What are you typing? To see the path, just type `echo %PATH%`

Answer (score -2):

The path environment variable is a list of directories. When you run a command, say `ipconfig`, Windows will try to find ipconfig in all directories present in the variable (i.e. `C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`).

To add a new directory to %PATH%: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\directory`. This is just for the current session.
To add a path once and for all: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Why didn't you include all relevant information in the answer itself?  The duplicate [question](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) has answer that did so.  There is absolutely no reason to link to that page.